# sql server except on stored procedure results

Tags: sql-server

I want to do this but with stored procedure results:

```
select * from table where column=whatever
except
select * from table2 where column=whatever
```

so

```
exec sp1 args
except
exec sp2 args
```

my sps don't have return values they just take arguments and return the results of select statements

Comment: You could fill temp tables with your SP's or use a table-valued-function or a view instead.

Comment: the sps I can't change but I could give temp tables a go

Answer (score 6):

Give this a go.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_sp1_Except_sp2
@sp1 args     --<-- All the params sp1 Expects
@sp2 args     --<-- All the params sp2 Expects
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SP1_Results') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #SP1_Results

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SP2_Results') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #SP2_Results


CREATE TABLE #SP1_Results
(
  -- Define table structure here
)

CREATE TABLE #SP2_Results
(
  -- Define table structure here
)


INSERT INTO #SP1_Results
EXECUTE dbo.sp1 @sp1

INSERT INTO #SP2_Results
EXECUTE dbo.sp2 @sp2

SELECT * FROM #SP1_Results
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM #SP2_Results

  SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
```